# PHP and MySQL on a MediaWiki Install

Tags: php, mysql, get, wiki, mediawiki

I have installed the extension SecurePHP to do a little bit of PHP coding, but I am having problems receiving data posted through the URL.

For example, I create a link to pass information like: http://server.com/pagename?process=lock&server=newserver I have also tried: http://server/index.php?title=pagename&process=lock&server=newserver

Then on the new page called pagename, I try to get the variables from the URL with php

$_GET['process'];
$_GET['server'];

And so on, but it's not working. Another solution I was willing to try was to put a brand new php page in the root of the server. /webroot/lock.php

Apache isn't reporting a 404, but the page isn't displaying the data I place in the file. Any ideas on how I can pass variables from on page to another to perform a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the output of:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

to see if you can pull any useful info about the request from there